# How can I add padding to <input type="button">?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, button

It's been couple of months since I've done some serious HTML/CSS coding, so I've probably missed a lot of things, but today I stumbled upon a really weird thing.

When I try to apply `padding` to a `<input type="submit">`, it doesn't work anymore.
I'm about 99% sure that I was able to do this, but now it seems as if it was impossible.

I even looked at one of my older projects, where I know I had padding on submit buttons, but they don't work anymore.

Here's a little demo of the problem

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="padding: 5px 10px;">
<button type="submit" value="Submit" style="padding: 5px 10px;">Submit</button>
```

and how it looks in Google Chrome 15 on Mac

[image]

but it doesn't seem to work in Firefox 4 at all

[image]

[Here's a link to the demo source on JSbin.com](http://jsbin.com/irogeq/4/edit)

I would bet that this was working about 6 months ago, but something must have changed. I've been using Windows Vista and OS X Snow Leopard with recent upgrade to Lion, but that doesn't seem like it.

Am I missing something?

**edit: fixing the typo DID NOT help. The padding still isn't applied to the first button.**

**edit2: After going through [Adobe Browserlab](http://browserlab.adobe.com) it looks like this is OS X specific problem. I'd still like to know how to do this even on OS X though.**

Comment: You've got a typo in your code. It should be `5px` in the `<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="padding: 5x 10px;">`, making it `<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="padding: 5px 10px;">`

Comment: As a note the only reason to use an `input[type="button"]` element would be with JavaScript. Because they are such a nuisance to style, just use an `a[href="#"]` element instead. As for `input[type="submit"]`...good luck.

Comment: when using padding on submit buttons do not forget that there is a nasty ie bug: http://latrine.dgx.cz/the-stretched-buttons-problem-in-ie to fix this use `overflow:visible`

Comment: @Sasha you're right, but it still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Darth Worked fine for me when testing. Have you tested in another environment?

Comment: @Sasha yes, it seems to be a problem only on OS X. It works fine on Windows. I'd still like to know how to work this around for OS X though.

Comment: I know this is old, but after hitting this issue myself recently and eventually finding a fix I thought I'd post an answer.

Answer (score 15):

This issue was apparent for me too on OS X Firefox. The solution is to disable the browser's default appearance before applying your own:

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

More info at: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Answer (score 9):

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" style="padding: 5x 10px;">`

You forgot the p in 5px. That is breaking the styling.

Comment: +1 (don't know if that's a question typo or the actual issue, but I gotta hand it to you, AWESOME eye :P)

Comment: wow ... at first I was about to say "omg I'm so stupid" ... but then I found out it still doesn't work, even after you fix the typo :\

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove browser default style button first, to do that i usually restyle it with change the background and border. Here is the snippet style i use if want to change the button

```
input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8C8C69;
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property:

```css
input[type="submit"] {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```